# Are FBML apps required to provide HTTPS canvas url by 1st of October?

Tags: facebook, https, fbml

Since FBML apps canvas url(s) are not directly accessible by the end user, I suppose not , but can anyone confirm this ?

Comment: That is a good question. I am interested too.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Confirm: "An SSL Certificate is required for all Canvas and Page Tab apps (not in Sandbox mode and not FBML)." See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/
Though I am currently getting mixed content warnings in IE and Firefox when using Facebook in https mode and then loading content over http in the app. So users of your app might get kinda bad feeling if you do not serve your content over https.</s>

---

**UPDATE:**

Facebook:

> "We have heard that there is some confusion about whether FBML apps
>   must support HTTPS. FBML developers still need to know whether users
>   are browsing Facebook over a secure connection since they need to
>   detect whether to serve iframe or video content over HTTPS. As a
>   result, FBML apps must obtain SSL certificates in order to serve this
>   type of content to users browsing over a secure connection. If you
>   have an FBML app, please obtain an SSL certificate for your app to
>   receive traffic from users browsing Facebook over a secure connection.
>
> If you enable SSL for your FBML app, please make sure that your SSL
>   certificate includes all intermediate certificates in the chain of
>   trust as our SSL validation is strict. You can use third-party SSL
>   analysis tools (e.g., https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html) to check
>   your certificate status and fix any errors (and warnings). If your SSL
>   certificate has problems, you may see "Empty response received" error
>   when you load your FBML canvas app."

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/567/

Comment: They've added info about FBML recently.